# Should Liquibase cope with concurrent initialisation?

Tags: liquibase

I'm running a Liquibase migration concurrently against a clean HSQLDB instance, and while one of the updates succeeds the other fails as so:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-7" liquibase.exception.LockException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: object name already exists: DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK in statement [CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (ID INT NOT NULL, LOCKED BOOLEAN NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED TIMESTAMP, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR(255), CONSTRAINT PK_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK PRIMARY KEY (ID))] [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (ID INT NOT NULL, LOCKED BOOLEAN NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED TIMESTAMP, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR(255), CONSTRAINT PK_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK PRIMARY KEY (ID))]
    at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.acquireLock(StandardLockService.java:216)
    at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.waitForLock(StandardLockService.java:155)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:194)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:190)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:186)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:179)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: object name already exists: DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK in statement [CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (ID INT NOT NULL, LOCKED BOOLEAN NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED TIMESTAMP, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR(255), CONSTRAINT PK_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK PRIMARY KEY (ID))] [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (ID INT NOT NULL, LOCKED BOOLEAN NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED TIMESTAMP, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR(255), CONSTRAINT PK_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK PRIMARY KEY (ID))]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:316)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:55)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:122)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:112)
    at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.init(StandardLockService.java:87)
    at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.acquireLock(StandardLockService.java:189)
```

Is this expected behaviour? Using Liquibase 3.4.1.

(Reason is that it's an automated test starting up a clean environment with two app nodes to force code to handle there being multiple nodes, and I run Liquibase on app node startup.)

Comment: To state the obvious I understand *why* it's happening - there's a check then act race condition where node 1 gets in and creates the lock table between node 2 checking for its existence and then trying to create it. I'm just wondering if it's conceptually a bug, as until now I've assumed Liquibase migrations are safe to run concurrently; and if it is a bug, if there's anything that can be done about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for pointing out the problem. The goal is to be safe to run concurrently and it should be good if the DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK table exists, but there is a time gap between checking if the table exists and attempting to create it if it doesn't that can cause the error you are seeing if the timing is just right/wrong.

I created https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2596 to track the issue and added a fix for 3.4.2 which will let Liquibase recover from a "table already exists" exception. That will avoid your problem and the later code that inserts into the table is what really does the distributed locking so you would still be safe from concurrent updates.